# Copy a Formatted Range of Cells from Microsoft Excel and Paste to Microsoft Word using Microsoft.Office.Interop for C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, excel-interop

How copy to the `Clipboard` and paste it into a `Word.Interop.Application.Document` properly? Or - if this isn't he best way to copy a formatted `Range` of cells from Excel to Word, what is a better way?

## Here's my current approach:

I copy a `Range` using `Interop.Excel`. I am able to retrieve the formatted range via the following method:

```
public Range ReadRange(int startRow, int endRow, int startCol, int endCol)
{
    return m_Worksheet.Range[m_Worksheet.Cells[startRow, startCol], m_Worksheet.Cells[endRow, endCol]];
}
```

I copy the `Range` to the `Clipboard` like this:

```
void CopyRangeToClipboard(int startRow, int endRow, int startCol, int endCol)
{
    var range = ReadRange(startRow, endRow, startCol, endCol);
    string format = System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Rtf;
    Clipboard.SetData(format, range);  
}
```

After copying to the `Clipboard`, I tried pasting from the `Clipboard` to the `Interop.Word.Application.Document`:

```
private void PasteWithFormatting(string findText)
{
    WdRecoveryType wdRecoveryType = WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting;

    m_Document.Activate();
    m_WordApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();

    try
    {
        _Word.Range replaceRange = m_Document.Content.Find(findText);

        //then, I just paste it where the replacement text is
        replaceRange.PasteAndFormat(wdRecoveryType);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        string replace1 = findText.Substring(0, findText.Length / 2);
        string replace2 = findText.Substring(findText.Length / 2);

        _Word.Range replaceRange = Document.Content.Find(replace1);

        replaceRange.PasteAndFormat(wdRecoveryType);
        FindAndReplaceText(Content, replace2, string.Empty);                
    }
}
```

## Here's what was actually copied over to the Word Document:

`System.__ComObject_`

Comment: Have you tried using `range.Copy()` instead of `Clipboard.SetData()` ?